# Meteor - disable animation for initial elements

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to fade in items from query, but not those already in db. So when user initially opens my app, items should appears normally, but next items (those added when user has app loaded) should be faded in. 
I don't know how to realize it in Meteor, because it hasn't some callback for each db query or something, so i don't know what items comes from initial query and what not(eg. what should be showed normally and what faded in). Meteor is amazing, but looks for me that some things should be done better. Is there a way how to do it?

Comment: It might help if you research fibers.

Comment: @Eric Leroy: can you be more specific what exactly i should look at?

Comment: I ran into a problem the other day that took me hours to figure out.  I was trying to connect to an api and use the callback.  Because Meteor is synchronous, it executed all code before being able to use the callback data.  Here is a link that describes callbacks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632073/meteor-fibers-loop-and-callback  when your callback code is complete using a fiber, then you can have your belated db query fade in.

Answer (score 0):

Subscriptions have a reactive `ready()` method. You could only fade in objects added after `ready()` becomes true.